# Fine Uploader referencing newly created DOM object in onComplete callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, fine-uploader

I've been messing around with this for quite some time. The deeper I get the more tweaks I need to make. My biggest issue id being able to correctly reference the created li item once it is created.

For exampled once an image is uploaded a new li item is created. Then I reference this li element to make various changes. Such as add in thumb nail and custom buttons. This reference is required for various reasons.

Most of everything is working fine from deleting to error output etc. However the way I find reference to the corresponding li element is broken.

From what I can tell on complete is as such

```
onComplete(String id, String name, Object responseJSON, XMLHttpRequest xhr)
```

There is no much data on this but from I can gather the ID is a number represented the uploaded image in the order of the list. Possibly an internal list which would mirror the outputted list.

So I've been marrying up this id with the index id of the array of li elements. This has allowed me to the located the correct completed li element and manipulate it.

So this works fine. The issue is when I'm deleting images. Image are deleted and then the li elements removed. However the issue is that the onComplete ID does not marry up with the with the index within the list.

I'm using a custom delete function as my images are saved in a database and other reasons. I will also run into the same issue when prepoluating the list. Currently I plan to pre-output a copy of the list with the relevant data in exactly the same way. I cannot find any information on prepopulating the fineuplader.

So is there a way to accurately reference the newly complete li elements? Once that is constant on most browsers? How is the best way to prepopulate the list?

Really a simple reference within the oncomplete handler to the new dom li element would be perfect. Or anything similar. I'm surprised it does not exist. Maybe it does but I cannot find any info on it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you are using the default Fine Uploader UI, and not FineUploaderBasic/core.  In that case, it's quite easy to get a handle on the DOM element Fine Uploader creates for the associated file.  For example, in an `onComplete` callback:

```
....
onComplete: function(id, name, response, xhrOrXdr) {
    var listItemEl = this.getItemByFileId(id);    
    // do something with this element
}
```

I've provided a non-jQuery example since your example code does not seem to use jQuery, even though you have tagged this question as jQuery.  In case you are using the jQuery plug-in, your code would look something like this:

```
$('#myFineUploaderContainer').on('complete', function(event, id, name, response, xhrOrXdr) {
    var $listItem = $(this).fineUploader('getItemByFileId', id);
    // do something with this jQuery object
});
```

Note that, in the above example, Fine Uploader versions 3.6 and older will return a Node/HTMLElement, while Fine Uploader 3.7 and newer will return the expected jQuery object.  I wrote the above example assuming you are using 3.7.

For more information on this and other API methods, options, and callbacks, see the documentation at http://docs.fineuploader.com.

Comment: Yeah with jQuery sorry. Wow. I wish I asked that days ago!!